Simplifying fractional powers and collecting coefficient list from it
Problem
I want to generalize a solution I already have for a simpler situation. In my case I need to collect coefficients from a variable assuming fractional powers and on. First I'll present some context and after that I'll show you my struggle.
Context
I have a code alre
ady working in a simple situation. Maybe that's not the more precise way of doing it but it does what needs to be done.
First, considering that
formulaA= 9 - 20 c z^2 + (15 + 16 c^2) z^4 - 
 20 c z^6 - (9 + 6 z^4 + 16 c^2 z^4 + 9 z^8 - 20 c (z^2 + z^6)) P[c];
Coefficient[formulaA,P[c],1]//FullSimplify
CoefficientList[%,z]//FullSimplify

I get:
-9 - 6 z^4 - 16 c^2 z^4 - 9 z^8 + 20 c (z^2 + z^6)`


{-9, 0, 20 c, 0, -2 (3 + 8 c^2), 0, 20 c, 0, -9}

as expected.
So what I want is this last list of coefficients of powers of z.
The struggle
Now, formulaA is way more complicated. The variable z will have different powers, fractional powers sometimes and more, it could have variables as powers! Look at that:
formulaA= (-r (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m)))^(1/
  r) (2 m (2 m (-1 + r) - r) (1 + r) z^(3 m) (-c + z^m) + 
    z^((2 (m + r))/
     r) ((-1 + 2 m) r (2 m + r) + 
       2 c r (2 r + m (3 - 5 r + m (-5 + 2 r))) z^
        m + ((-1 + 2 m) r (2 m + r) + 
          4 c^2 (m + r) (-r + m (-1 + 2 r))) z^(2 m) - 
       2 c (r + m (2 + r)) (-r + m (-1 + 2 r)) z^(3 m))) + (-1)^(1/r)
   r^(1/r) z (z^m)^(1/m + 2/r) (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^(1/
  r) (-2 m (-1 + r) r (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^2 + 
    r^2 (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^2 + 
    2 m^2 (-2 r + c (-2 + 5 r) z^m - 
       2 (-1 + r + c^2 (-1 + 2 r)) z^(2 m) + c (-2 + 5 r) z^(3 m) - 
       2 r z^(4 m))) P[c]

When proceeding in the way I already did it is not enough.
(-1)^(1/r) r^(1/r) z (z^m)^(
 1/m + 2/r) (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(
   2 m))^(1/r) (-2 m (-1 + r) r (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^2 + 
   r^2 (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^2 + 
   2 m^2 (-2 r + c (-2 + 5 r) z^m - 
      2 (-1 + r + c^2 (-1 + 2 r)) z^(2 m) + c (-2 + 5 r) z^(3 m) - 
      2 r z^(4 m)))

(-1)^(1/r) r^(1/r) z (z^m)^(
 1/m + 2/r) (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(
   2 m))^(1/r) (-2 m (-1 + r) r (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^2 + 
   r^2 (1 - 2 c z^m + z^(2 m))^2 + 
   2 m^2 (-2 r + c (-2 + 5 r) z^m - 
      2 (-1 + r + c^2 (-1 + 2 r)) z^(2 m) + c (-2 + 5 r) z^(3 m) - 
      2 r z^(4 m)))

How can I create a list, that will group factors of the same power of z and more, in a way that it is possible to know which power it is (I mean, this factors are factors of who?)?

Does z represent a positive real number? Does m represent an integer? Is m always positive? Any other assumptions?

Z should be any complex number different than 0, m and r integers greater than 1

If formulaA were expressed as a finite sum c_1 z^p1 + ... + c_n z^pn, then it is easy to collect all the coefficients along with powers of z. That is why the first example worked. But your second formulaA is not of this form but contains a factor like (1 - 2 c z^m + z^2m)^(1/r), it impossible to get finite list.
